# How to properly pad matrix rows in C++

Tags: c++, g++

I want to store a dense N*M matrix in row-major order, and have every row aligned to some memory boundary (meaning rows may require some padding). N and M are known at compile time.

If I define something like this:

```
typedef struct __attribute__((aligned(64))) { element_t in[M]; } row_t;
typedef row_t matrix_t[N];
```

I get what I want, but I have to access elements as `m[row].in[col]` instead of the simpler `m[row][col]`.

I hoped to be able to do the following:

```
typedef __attribute__(aligned(64)) element_t row_t[M];
typedef row_t matrix_t[N];
```

but g++ complains that

```
test.cc:11: error: alignment of array elements is greater than element size
```

I know I can use my struct row_t version, and override the indexing operators to give me the simpler syntax:

```
typedef struct __attribute__((aligned(64))) {
    element_t in[M];
    element_t &operator[](const int idx) {
        return in[idx];
    }
} row_t;
typedef row_t matrix_t[N]
```

This works but is complicated and not very aesthetically pleasing.

Surely there must be a better way to do this ?

Comment: For what it's worth, this kind of operator overloading is pretty standard, and IMO no more ugly than anything in boost or many other "good" C++ libraries. I've used it before on (relatively) high-performance code, and I can't think of another good way to get the syntax you want without major changes.